# Execute 2 bash commands on same line

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I made a bash script to output the content for the `*txt` files and to print also the name of the file executed on the same line. But for no reason the first line has only the output and the next line has the name of the first output + the output of the next file.
How can I have the `file name` + `output`?

```
for i in *.txt; do cat "$i" && echo -n "$i"; done
```

Outputs:

```
ignore
alex.txt11111
alex1.txtda
alex2.txtnu
alex3.txt
```

Correct would be

```
alex.txt ignore; alex1.txt 11111; alex2.txt da; alex3.txt nu
```

Comment: Please reformat your post. Add 4 leading spaces to make code in code block. I'll try to do it , I don't know where ignore goes. So first ouptut the filename, then content? `echo -n "$i" && cat "$i"`??

Comment: @KamilCuk thx for help.
I workedd :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the contents of the file first, then printing its name without a newline (`echo -n`). You should do the opposite: print the name without a newline, but with an extra space at the end, then print the contents of the file.

```
for f in *.txt; do
    echo -n "$f "
    cat "$f"
done
```

Comment: Prefer `printf '%s ' "$f"` to `echo -n`; this avoids having to worry about how exactly your shell is implementing `echo` (as there are numerous compile- and run-time options that can affect it).

Comment: Also, as it appears each file is expected to have only one line, you can use `IFS= read -r line < "$f"; printf '%s %s\n' "$f" "$line` to avoid running the external program `cat`.